# Having trouble binding DataGridCell value to send to converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following converter below which is throwing a runtime error of:

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Text'
>   property not found on 'object' ''ContentPresenter' (Name='')'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Content.Text; DataItem='DataGridCell'
>   (Name=''); target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'IsTextMatch' (type 'Boolean')

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <helpers:SearchValueConverter x:Key="SearchValueConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="helpers:SearchBehaviours.IsTextMatch">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(helpers:SearchBehaviours.SearchValue)" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="helpers:SearchBehaviours.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Can someone see what the issue is?

Comment: Hi there, your converter is expecting an array of objects i.e. `object[] values` if I would do this I would try casting it to a `FrameworkElement` and then jus use `FrameworkElement.DataContext as int or string`. And like @Grant Winney said use Content. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object in `DataGridCell.Content` may not have a `Text` property.

Try binding to `Content`:

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content" />
```

And then test for the type of "content":

```
public object Convert(object[] values, ...
{
    var textBlock = values[0] as TextBlock;

    if (textBlock != null)
    {
        // do something with textBlock.Text ...
```

Comment: DataGridCell.Content does have a Text property. In my case I found that I had manipulated some of the columns with a template so it found Text for a majority of them and then threw an error for the others. However your answer was still correct I used Content and then checked if was a TextBlock or not, if so got the Text property.